# Need to find mapView region changed by user manually dragged or automatically focusing

Tags: ios, swift

I have mapView with some annotations. I need to do separate action for both user dragged region change and set region(Automatically focus). Is there any way to find user dragged manually or not while regionDidChangeAnimated method calling.

I have checked all default properties for MKMapView, MKVisibleRect, region. There is no property related to finding for detect map view changed with user dragged manually or not

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to do this using a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

I have used, with success, A UIPanGestureRecognizer like the following:

```
lazy var mapPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    let gr = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedMap))
    gr.delegate = self
    return gr
}()
```

You will also have to add the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the map with

```
yourMap.addGestureRecognizer(mapPanGestureRecognizer)
```

You can then manage what happens in the #selector function by checking the [state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1619998-state) of the gesture, like so

```
@objc func draggedMap(panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Check to see the state of the passed panGestureRocognizer
    if panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        // Do something
    }
}
```